# Dynamic SVG with Meteor

Tags: javascript, svg, meteor

I have an SVG temperature gauge that I pull dynamic data into. I have no problem displaying the data from the mongo document however I'm really stuck trying to figure out how to take a value from the returned data and apply it to a formula to set an the X position of an SVG element (tempBarXPosition).

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
// This code only runs on the client
  pullTempData = Tasks.find({_id: "scQGmhzsCffJeGqt"});
  Template.body.helpers({
    resData: function () {
      return pullTempData;
    },
  tempBarXposition: function(){
    return pullTempData.temperature + 50; // <---- this doesn't work
  }
});
```

Is it possible to reference the value of {{temperature}} that is returned with the pullTempData object within the helper function itself?

HTML file (the first line doesn't work... the 2nd does)

```
<line fill="none" stroke="#e5e5e5" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" x1="{{tempBarXPosition}}" y1="280" x2="{{tempBarXPosition}}" y2="250" id="temp_bar"/>
<text fill="#00ff00" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-opacity="0" x="66.875" y="300.25" font-size="20" font-family="Sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve" id="temp_value">{{temperature}}</text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, your `pullTempData` is a cursor. Try that to get a document:

```
//Use findOne() to have a document
pullTempData = Tasks.findOne({_id: "scQGmhzsCffJeGqt"});
```

Or if you prefer:

```
//Use find().fetch()[0] to get the first element of the cursor, if any!
pullTempData = Tasks.find({_id: "scQGmhzsCffJeGqt"}).fetch()[0];
```